# Is this conclusion on orders of magnitude correct?

Tags: approximation-theory

Let $f(n_1,n_2) = \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{n_1n_2^2}{(n_1-n_2)^3}\right)$, where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are natural numbers. If $n_1\propto n_2$, that is, if the two variables grow proportionally, is it true that $f(n_1,n_2) =\mathcal{O}(1)$?

Comment: Do you understand under proportionality $n_1=n_2 \cdot k$, where $k \ne 1$ is constant?

Comment: thanks for the comment. the point is that if $k=1$, the ratio blows up. So I guess the result is not true in general. I'm I correct?

Comment: I guess you are right. thanks!

Comment: Of course for $k=1$ it losts sense. Can we consider it as part of general case? And very important is how you understand proportionality - do you call $n_1=k \cdot n_2 + b$ proportional or only $n_1=k \cdot n_2 $ ?

Comment: It is the first kind, indeed $n_1>n_2+4$, if that matters. Why is the difference important?

Comment: Because in case $n_1=k \cdot n_2 +b$ we can take $k=1$ and then fraction will not be bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the coefficient of proportionality. If it is different from $1$, yes. If not, $f$ will tend to infinity.

For instance, if $n_1(k) = k$, and $n_2(k) = k-1$, it is easy to see that $\frac{n_1n_2^2}{(n_1-n_2)^3} \simeq k^3$ as $k$ tends to infinity.

However, if, say $n_1(k) \geq (1+\delta) n_2(k)$, where $\delta >0$, this cannot happen.

Comment: Yes, that was my doubt. The result is true only if $n_1$ grows faster than $n_2$, but still at a linear rate.